# UI Automation- Object recognition issue using Coded UI

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, ui-automation, coded-ui-tests

I am working on UI Automation of a **WPF** application using Visual Studio **Coded UI**.

I have generated my scripts using record feature and all the required objects are added to designer file. 
But when I play my scripts some time object's of AUT(Application Under Test) are recognised but sometimes objects are is not getting recognized. Coded UI is unable to recognize and play the scripts.

can any one suggest a way so that objects can be recognized every time i run the script.

Comment: I think by giving Automation ID to WPF controls(this should be done in application that you are testing) and using this Automation ID in Coded UI should enable to identify element every time. A very lengthy procedure I know but this will ensure that elements are recognised every time.

Comment: Hi User, Automation id is always generated automatically for all the object that we record. So can you tell me whats the lengthy procedure you were discussing above to make the object recognize every time.

Comment: Lengthy procedure is about giving meaningful AutomationID over auto generated as it is better to rely on explicit name rather than auto generated one. And if application is already developed then it needs to be carried out for each control.